# brew doctor: Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, dylib

running

> brew doctor

gives me this:

> Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib. If you didn't
>   put them there on purpose they could cause problems when building
>   Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected dylibs:
>
> /usr/local/lib/libqmi_api.dylib
>
> /usr/local/lib/libvousb.dylib

anyone know what these dylibs are?

Comment: I think they have something to do with an old VodaPhone driver for 3G modem I installed long ago...I just removed them but if someone knows for sure please do let me know - cheers! :)

Comment: FWIW, I have also had this problem, and they were in fact Vodafone libraries.

Answer (score 10):

I think you shoud try to upgrade these library, if you still need them. 
I had the same problem with **libusb** and I resolved it by "brewing" an upgrade.

```
brew upgrade libqmi_api
brew upgrade libvousb
```

Sometime, brew can't symlink the lib into /usr/local. This occurs when you already have a old symlinked version of your lib.

```
brew link --overwrite libusb
```

should do the stuff.

Here is my testcase with **libusb** library :

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib

$ brew upgrade libusb
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
libusb 1.0.9
==> Upgrading libusb
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libusb/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0.9/libusb-1.0.9.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9
==> make install
Warning: Could not link libusb. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libusb'

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9: 11 files, 420K, built in 9 seconds

$ brew link --overwrite libusb
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.9... 5 symlinks created

$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
$
```

Hope this helps.